# If $f^{-1}((r,\infty))$ is measurable for all $r$ in $\mathbb{Q}$, prove that $f$ is measurable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a function, for which the sets $f^{-1}((r,\infty))$ are measurable for $\forall r \in \mathbb{Q}$. I'm asked to prove that $f$ is measurable.

---

This is what I've done:

Let's take any $\alpha , \beta  \in \mathbb{R}$, being $\alpha < \beta$ . Then, $\exists r \in \mathbb{Q}$ where $\alpha \le r < \beta$. By hypothesis we know that $f^{-1}((r,\infty))=\{x\in \mathbb{R}:f(x)>r\}$ is a measurable set. So, $f^{-1}((\alpha,\infty))=\{x\in \mathbb{R}:f(x)> \alpha \}$ is also going to be measurable (I'm not sure if I can say this last sentence... May I prove it? I don't know how to do it).

So consecuently, as $f^{-1}((\alpha,\infty))$ is a measurable set for $\forall \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, $f$ is a measurable function.

Comment: What is your definition of what it means to be measurable?

Comment: It's not clear that you've proved anything.  You claim that $f^{-1}(\alpha, \infty)$ is measurable, which is just a direct consequence of what you're already assuming is true.

Comment: True.. I've got that that set is measurable for $r \in \mathbb{Q}$ and I want to see that is also true for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. But I don't know how @D_S

Comment: @D_S It's a lower-level statement, so they probably need to prove that $f^{-1}(\alpha, \infty)$ is measurable.  It's not simply an instance of the assumption, even if it's only one step away.

Comment: That's it. I have to prove that $f^{-1}((\alpha, \infty))$ is measurable for $\forall \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ @BrianMoehring how can I do it?

Comment: @User160 Remember that the countable union of measurable sets is measurable.  Write $f^{-1}(\alpha, \infty)$ explicitly as a countable union of measurable sets.

Comment: I've got a measurable set which is $f^{-1}((r, \infty))$ $r \in \mathbb{Q}$ but which other set can I take? @BrianMoehring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\alpha$ is any real number, you want to show that $f^{-1}(\alpha, \infty)$ is measurable.  You know that $f^{-1}(r,\infty)$ is measurable whenever $r$ is rational.  So let $r_1 > r_2 > r_3 > \cdots$ be a sequence of rational numbers which converges to $\alpha$.  Then clearly the union of the intervals $(r_i,\infty)$ satisfies

$$\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} (r_i, \infty) = (\alpha,\infty).$$

And therefore

$$f^{-1}(\alpha,\infty) = f^{-1} \Bigg( \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} (r_i, \infty) \Bigg).$$

Finish the proof by using the fact that the inverse image of a union of sets is the union of the inverse images, and that a countable union of measurable sets is measurable.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how would this change if we instead had $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{\overline R}$?   We would have to make any special caveats for trying to show that $f^{-1}(r,\infty])$ is measurable instead of just $f^{-1}(r,\infty)$?

Comment: It should work the same way.  Or, use what was just proved, and say $$f^{-1}(r,\infty] = f^{-1}(r, \infty) \cup f^{-1} \{\infty \}$$ is measurable as the union of two measurable sets.

Comment: Ah, of course!  Thank you.